# open new window using var and get it's property href in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using var to store my new PopUp window and want to get that window's property href using that var.

In chrome it's working fine but in firefox it is giving me  an error like below.

> SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "origin" on cross-origin object

Comment: How do you open PopUp? Share your code, pls

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Get it</button>

<script>
var win = "";
function myFunction() {
  win = window.open("https://www.google.com/", 'popUpWindow', 'height=400,width=600,left=10,top=10,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no');
}
function myFunction1() {
  alert(win.location.href);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Edit the question, please don't add blocks of code to comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in Firefox, see fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/designtocode/4n17Lws6/3/

```
var win = ""; 
function myFunction() { 
win = window.open("google.com", 'popUpWindow', 'height=400,width=600,left=10,top=10,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no'); 
} 

function myFunction1() { 
alert(win.location.href); 
}
```

Update:

Instead of using google.com, use the full address i.e. http://www.google.com

https://jsfiddle.net/designtocode/4n17Lws6/4/

```
var win = ""; 
function myFunction() { 
win = window.open("http://www.google.com", 'popUpWindow', 'height=400,width=600,left=10,top=10,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no'); 
} 

function myFunction1() { 
alert(win.location.href); 
}
```

Comment: Hi,Yes that is working in some of case but for our website it is not working so i think there should be some feature to turn on or off.

Comment: @NiraliAkabari it's very difficult to assist as this looks like it's your specific website issue. What you could do is paste your entire code of your website page and maybe someone can assist you further.

Comment: Thanks For reply. but that's not possible as i need to keep it secure.:)